# Jmeter BSF Sampler JavaScript debugging

Tags: javascript, debugging, jmeter

Is there a good way to debug my BSF Sampler written in JavaScript using Jmeter? For instance, using console.log() in the browser is often used. Is there a method like that where I can see the output in Jmeter?

Comment: did you find have any solution yet?

Comment: Nope. My current debugging method is setting user variables in the BSF JS sampler... It sucks. I really would like to find a better debugging method.

Comment: To add, its also difficult when there is a problem in the JS file. There isn't an error, it just doesn't run. I wish I knew definitively when there is an exception.

Comment: I'm experience the same issue, and still not find a solution too...

Answer (score 12):

JavaScript can use the logger from JMeter and its log levels e.g. debug, info

try:

```
log.info("Hello World!");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `print()` command for this.  It will write to the Jmeter console.

Comment: BlackGaff: I'm afraid your methods only works with BeanShell Post Processor

Answer (score 0):

You can place calls to OUT.println to your javascripts in the BSF Sampler, BSF PreProcessor, BSF PostProcessor. This will write lines to the jmeter console window. For example:

```
OUT.println("hello world");
```